# Call `Current` for IEnumerable<T> using Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, reflection.emit, il

Please advise how can I build call of property `Current` and `MoveNext` of `IEnumerable<byte>`.

#### Target

I'd like to get something like:

```
var bytesEnumerator = byteArray.EnumerateArray();
var controlByte = bytesEnumerator.Current;
bytesEnumerator.MoveNext();
```

#### Variant 1

Here is code:

```
LocalBuilder lbBytesEnumerator = il.DeclareLocal(typeof (IEnumerator<byte>));
// Get enumerator over bytes
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(ByteConverter).GetMethod("EnumerateArray"), new[] { typeof(byte[]) } );
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, lbBytesEnumerator);

.......
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_S, lbBytesEnumerator);
il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(IEnumerator<byte>).GetProperty("Current").GetGetMethod(), null);
LocalBuilder lbControlByte = il.DeclareLocal(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, lbControlByte);


// Enumerator Move Next
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_S, lbBytesEnumerator);
il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(List<byte>.Enumerator).GetMethod("MoveNext"), null);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
```

Failed with:

> {"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."}

#### Variant 2

And when I store enumerator by address (Ldloc_S -> Ldloca_S)

```
......
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloca_S, lbBytesEnumerator);
il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, typeof(IEnumerator<byte>).GetProperty("Current").GetGetMethod(), null);
LocalBuilder lbControlByte = il.DeclareLocal(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, lbControlByte);
```

It fails with:

> {"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."}

### Update:

Enumerate array returns Enumerator based not on List but it's yielding results:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            yield return array[i];
```

Comment: What is `List<byte>.Enumerator` ?

Comment: @leppie: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x854yt9s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I suspect the first error is because you've modified the list after calling `GetEnumerator` - in the code indicated by `...`

Comment: What if you write the code in C#, compile it and and then disassemble it? Perhaps that could give an indication on how you could code it?

Comment: @JonSkeet: Bit that would be different from `IEnumerator<byte>` as used elsewhere which `lbBytesEnumerator` is declared as. (which may cause the exception, due to not using `CallVirt`).

Comment: BTW, you need to use `CallVirt` for generally unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: @leppie: I dare say it would. I was only answering your question about what the type is :)

Comment: @JanSommer I've rewrite my sample code on C# (make it more accurate) and it helped me.
@leppie: I've get `call` from me disassembled code that was wrong. Right version is disassembled with `callvirt`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: thnx for the link. I haven't check underlying code that provide enumerator for me, and try disassemble code that base on List as source of enumeration. But actually our custom method `EnumerateArray` iterates through array and yield results. Now I've fix my code and it works.

Comment: @JonSkeet: My question was more to poke the OP on the intention of using that ;p I guessed it was some implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed code:

```
                // Control byte
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, lbBytesEnumerator);
                il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(IEnumerator<byte>).GetProperty("Current").GetGetMethod(), null);
                LocalBuilder lbControlByte = il.DeclareLocal(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc, lbControlByte);
                // Enumerator Move Next
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, lbBytesEnumerator);
                il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(IEnumerator).GetMethod("MoveNext"), null);
                il.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke your code, you have to work with Types and MethodInfos, not TypeBuilders and MethodBuilders.

So, you need to CreateType() and then use that Type and its method:

```
var generatedType = typeBuilder.CreateType();

var funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(
generatedType, typeof(IEnumerable<string>));
var d = generatedType.GetMethod("MoveNext").CreateDelegate(funcType);
```